# d3.js Odd Rotation Behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm in the early stages of a JS project. Everything is going fine so far except for the positioning of one shape. The shape in question is a teal diamond (square rotated 45 degrees). I can get the square on the screen no problem, but when I add:

```
    .attr("transform", "rotate(45)")
```

the square rotates properly, but shifts towards the left portion of the screen, like this:

[image]

I am not sure what is causing this to happen. If it helps, here is some of the code that produced this result:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);
        svg
            .append("rect")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(45)")
            .attr("x", 250)
            .attr("height", w / 10)
            .attr("width", w / 10)
            .attr("fill", "teal")
```

Note: If I put the "y" attribute in, the square disappears completely.

What is causing this? Did I do something wrong that I just can't see?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you rotate the rect, you also rotate its coordinate system. So when you later move it 250 along the x axis, you're actually moving it 250 units along a 45 degree axis -- the result of the rotation.

As a rule, when you introduce a `transform` attribute as you did for `rotate`, you should do all your transformation via this attribute. So, you need to use `translate` instead of using the `"x"` attribute. Then it would look like this:

```
svg
  .append("rect")
  .attr("transform", "translate(250, 0) rotate(45)")
  // remove this: .attr("x", 250)
  .attr("height", w / 10)
  ...
```

This gets you the results I think you're looking for. Now note that the order of transformations matters here: if your transform was `"rotate(45) translate(250, 0)"` (i.e. first rotate then translate), you'd get the same, wrong results you got before. That's because when you rotate first, your translation happens, as before, along a rotated x axis.

Comment: Ahhh you are absolutely right. Thanks a lot. So now I need the shape to be exactly in the center. Using the Pythagorean Theorm, I found the length of the cross section, and divided it by 2. The result of that equation is what I want to set as the y coordinate in my translate statement (subtracted from the canvas height / 2 of course). It seems as if I cannot use variables here though. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: Don't need to use Pythagorean, as long as you're doing the transformation in the right order. Assuming `w` and `h` are the canvas size, and `rw` and `rh` are the Rect's size, this should do what you're asking: `.attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ") rotate(45) translate(" + (-rw/2) + "," + (-rh/2) + ")"`. In other words, first move top-left of rect to the center, then rotate 45, then move back half-width and half-height of rect -- along 45 degrees axis -- which centers it. If canvas is 300x300 and rect is 100x100: `"translate(150,150) rotate(45) translate(-50,-50)"`

Comment: Interesting. I already set up Pythagorean's in my code, but if your method is faster, I may swap it up. Thanks a lot for all the help.

Answer (score 12):

In SVG you must set the transform origin to get it to rotate from the center, such as...

```
.attr("transform", "rotate(45, 250, 100)");
```

Where `250, 100` is the x and y position of your rect minus it's radius. Putting it all together it would look like...

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 400)
            .attr("height", 300);
        svg
            .append("rect")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(30,"+ (diamond.x+diamond.width/2) + ","+ (diamond.y+diamond.width/2) +")")
            .attr("x", diamond.x)
            .attr("y", diamond.y)
            .attr("height", diamond.width)
            .attr("width", diamond.width)
            .attr("fill", "teal")​
```

You can view a demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/uwM8u/

Comment: Already got the answer for the rotation, but your code snippet helped me out a lot with the syntax for the rotate attribute. Thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks. I was having problems getting them to rotate around their center. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach slightly different from the answer Duopixel gave. Here you are not repeating the  calculations for X and Y.  In Duopixel's example, its a trivial improvement since he is merely referencing a structure. Its often the case that X and Y are functions and I would not want to maintain that loging in two places. 
This approach allows you to set X and Y a node, then rotate on the center of said node.

You may find that after the rotation, you still want to  tweak the final position, which could be done with another transform, or in the case of TEXT, you can use dx, dy.

```
    svgNode.attr("transform", function (d) {

                    var w = +d3.select(this).attr("x") +  (this.getBBox().width / 2) ;
                    var h = +d3.select(this).attr("y") + (this.getBBox().height / 2);

                    return  "rotate(90," + w + "," + h + ")";

                })
```