# D3.js - How to rotate the texts on each bar of a grouped bar chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rotation, bar-chart, label

I'm workng with d3.js and don't haveso many experiences with it. I have a grouped bar chart with the values written on each bar (horizontal). How can I rotate them so that they are vertical (rotated 90°)? My code:

```
bars.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y0(d.value1) + 3; })
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value1; });

       bars.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name) + barWidth / (2.25); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y1(d.value2) + 3; })
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value2; });

       bars.append("text")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name) + barWidth / (4.0); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y2(d.value3) + 3; })
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value3; });

       bars.append("text")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name) + barWidth / (1.5); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y3(d.value4) + 3; })
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
       .text(function(d) { return d.value4; });
```

Comment: `bars.selectAll("text").attr("transform", "rotate(90)")`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434850/how-to-align-text-vertically-on-a-node-within-a-sankey-diagram-d3-js/23441408#23441408).

I believe you are coming across the same problem as described in the linked answer (and in the question itself) - your rotation is around a corner of a bar, not around the center! And that's why labels disappear!

Just want to highlight what was the solution to the linked problem: use a composite transformation that consists of a translation and a rotation. The code from example looks like this: (and yours should look similar; you just have to understand the code from linked jsfiddles before you apply the same strategy to your situation)

```
  node.selectAll("text.nodeValue")
      .text(function (d) { return formatNumber(d.value); })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("transform", function (d) {
           return "rotate(-90) translate(" +
                       (-d.dy / 2) +
                       ", " +
                       (sankey.nodeWidth() / 2 + 5) +
       ")";});
```

Before/after pictures:

### BEFORE

[image]

### AFTER

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In svg it is quite easy to move/rotate an element using the `transform` attribute. Hence you can do (as suggested by Lars Kotthoff):

```
bars.selectAll("text").attr("transform","rotate(90)")
```

Also, from the code you posted, I would recommend you to have a look at selections in order to not generate each bar legend by hand. This tutorial can help you for this: [Let's Make a Bar Chart](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/)

Comment: when I try this the labels just disappear. I think that I could solve this by using `.attr("transform","rotate(90) translate(?)")` - am I right? But then I don't know what to write in the brackets of translate.