# Rotation with transition

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

As stated in previous questions (for example [d3.js Odd Rotation Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985077/d3-js-odd-rotation-behavior)), when you want to rotate an SVG object on its place you should use

```
.attr('transform','rotate(45,100,100)')
```

where the first number is the rotation degrees, and the other two are the coordinates of the rotation origin.

The problem here is that I want to execute the rotation inside a transition:

```
.transition()
.attr('transform', 'rotate(45,100,100)')
.duration(300)
```

and I get a strange behaviour, I can see a translation before the expected rotation.
You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/uwM8u/121/

Is there a better way to obtain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The D3 way to do this is to use a [custom tween function](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3305854), which in this case is a simple string interpolation:

```
.attrTween("transform", function() {
  return d3.interpolateString(d3.select(this).attr("transform"),
      "rotate(" + (rotation+=45) + "," +
        (diamond.x+diamond.width/2) + "," +
        (diamond.y+diamond.width/2) + ")");
})
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uwM8u/130/).

Answer (score 1):

Add a parent `<g>` element with the translation so you are actually rotating the shape about the origin.

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 400)
            .attr("height", 300);
        svg         
            .append("text")
            .text("click the square")
            .attr("x", w/2)
            .attr("y", w/2)
        svg
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + diamond.x + "," + diamond.y +")")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(" + rotation + ")")
            .attr("x", -diamond.width / 2)
            .attr("y", -diamond.width / 2)
            .attr("height", diamond.width)
            .attr("width", diamond.width)
            .attr("fill", "teal")
            .on("mousedown", function(){
              d3.select(this)
                  .transition()
                  .attr("transform", "rotate("+ (rotation+=45) +")")
                 .duration(300)           
            });
```

or as a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/uwM8u/134/)

Comment: This solution doesn't work, because during the transition, the rotation is composed of two different transitions, with different timing.
You can check it here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwM8u/133/)

Comment: Your jsfiddle is not the same as my example! I've added a corrected jsfiddle to the answer for you.